# upgrade of wagtail from 2.15 to 4.1.5 lost content

Tags: wagtail

I upgraded wagtail from 2.15.6 to wagtail 3.0.3 and then 4.0.4 every thing worked fine no errors apart from a couple of test errors
Then I upgraded to 4.1.5 and on Pages / Edit the pages display content titles but no content, no errors in log

log is when trying to login as superuser without input boxes

```
[08/May/2023 08:49:29] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9147
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/core/css/global.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/css/core.css?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailmedia/css/wagtailmedia-comparison.css?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/core/css/environment_dev_theme.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtail_modeltranslation/css/page_editor_modeltranslation.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/core/css/editor.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtail_modeltranslation/css/admin_patch.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailmedia/css/wagtailmedia.css?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery.datetimepicker.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery-3.6.0.min.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.13.2.min.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/jquery.autosize.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/bootstrap-modal.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/bootstrap-transition.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor/tag-it.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/core.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/vendor.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/wagtailadmin.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/telepath/telepath.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/js/sidebar.js?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/images/wagtail-logo.svg?v=824298ec HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[08/May/2023 08:49:30] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9154
```

I have resolved issue, I added custom filter to custom fields.html that filtered out content, reworked
Thanks cnn for advice

Comment: Without more details I doubt we can be much help. Are you sure all was well in Wagtail 4.0? That had more changes than the 4.1 release. You said no errors in your logs, what about errors in the browser console? Perhaps you are not loading the admin css/js for the correct version.

Comment: I cannot login as superuser now as login page has no input boxes, getting console error in browser
fused to execute script from 'http://cms.trade.great:8010/admin/login/?next=/admin/jsi18n/' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: does not work in chrome or safari

Comment: That sounds more like changes to your hosting setup than changes to your wagtail code - probably changes to how you are serving static files. Look carefully at the server logs for your JS and CSS assets. Are they all serving? or do you have 404 or 403 errors there?

Comment: I'm running this locally with django serving static files

Comment: using dev server runserver

Comment: See all those return codes of 304? That means your browser is using cached assets. Start by using your browser's dev tools to make sure you do NOT see cached assets. That's the only way to tell if changes you make on the server are correct. Once you are using the current server assets, then you can try to figure out if those files are updated to Wagtail 4.1